# How to navigate a webpage with python

Tags: python, web

I was made a python script for bruteforce (pen test) but before the bruteforce start, I need to go through some links clicking and login, so I want to do those stuff with python. Basically when I start that script it should login and click some links then start the bruteforce.

so, is there any way I can make my python script to do those basic stuff for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check these:

- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [Spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)
- [webkit](http://www.webkit.org/)

These tools will help you to emulate browser via script.